# How to dynamically change an ajax call to an api in azure functions?

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, azure-functions

I am iterating over an array, and foreach item I am making an api call to azure functions.

I need pass the 'ticketKey' to azure, and then append the ticketkey to the call i am asking azure to make.

Tried sending the ticketkey in the request header of the ajax call, but not sure how to receive that in the azure code and append it to the call i am making from there.

Just to be clear, the ajax request goes to azure functions, which then runs the code you seen below the initial ajax call.

I need to somehow get to the contents of the ajax call `(ticketKey)` and append that to the azure functions call

`(var content = await client.GetStringAsync(https://blah.com/rest/api/2/issue/{ticketKey})`

My Ajax call:

```
 var GetTicketInfo = myArray.forEach(function(ticketKey){


    $.ajax
      ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://blahblah.azurewebsites.net/api/blahblah",
        dataType: 'json',
        headers : {"ticketKey": ticketKey},
        async: false,
        success: function (res){
        console.log(res);
}
    });

});
```

My Azure functions code:

```
public static class azureApicall
{
    [FunctionName("AzureCall")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var user = "blah";
        var pass = "blah";
        var pair = $"{user}:{pass}";
        var bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pair);
        var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
        var authValue = $"Basic {base64}";
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(authValue);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));


        var content = await client.GetStringAsync("https://blah.com/rest/api/2/issue/{ticketKey}");
        return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(content);
    }
}
```

the error message when i debug:

```
[08/11/2019 11:08:02] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '0000000000000000000000000359A6B5'.
[08/11/2019 11:08:02] Executing HTTP request: {
[08/11/2019 11:08:02]   "requestId": "4739380b-c445-4bb9-8bbc-dd27e1682a63",
[08/11/2019 11:08:02]   "method": "POST",
[08/11/2019 11:08:02]   "uri": "/api/ConfluenceWidgetTeamCity"
[08/11/2019 11:08:02] }
[08/11/2019 11:08:03] Executing 'ConfluenceWidgetTeamCity' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=72e4c354-299d-4105-9e3d-56a119c5cd6a)
[08/11/2019 11:08:03] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
[08/11/2019 11:08:03] Executed 'ConfluenceWidgetTeamCity' (Succeeded, Id=72e4c354-299d-4105-9e3d-56a119c5cd6a)
[08/11/2019 11:08:03] Executed HTTP request: {
[08/11/2019 11:08:03]   "requestId": "4739380b-c445-4bb9-8bbc-dd27e1682a63",
[08/11/2019 11:08:03]   "method": "POST",
[08/11/2019 11:08:03]   "uri": "/api/ConfluenceWidgetTeamCity",
[08/11/2019 11:08:03]   "identities": [
[08/11/2019 11:08:03]     {
[08/11/2019 11:08:03]       "type": "WebJobsAuthLevel",
[08/11/2019 11:08:03]       "level": "Admin"
[08/11/2019 11:08:03]     }
[08/11/2019 11:08:03]   ],
[08/11/2019 11:08:03]   "status": 400,
[08/11/2019 11:08:03]   "duration": 579
[08/11/2019 11:08:03] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `Headers` from the `HttpRequest` to get your ticketKey. Example

```
req.Headers.TryGetValue("ticketKey", out var result);
var ticketKey= result.FirstOrDefault();
```

Then you can use the `ticketKey` variable's value in your request.

```
var content = await client.GetStringAsync($"https://blah.com/rest/api/2/issue/{ticketKey}");
```

#### Update - Adding image

Requst from postman

[image: Postman request]

As you can see i have the `ticketKey` header value passed with value called `dummy`

Here's VS breakpoint

[image]

Comment: hmmm not quite what i'm after, I get a net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in the console when i do that.

Comment: @AndyStav are you not using Visual Studio in local ?

Comment: I am, but just to mention azure incase that makes any difference

Comment: @AndyStav put a breakpoint on your code and check. I will edit my answer and add a image for example

Comment: mybreak point doesnt seem to hit when i debug the applciation?
in the terminal i see this error, please look above in edited post:

Comment: thank you, this worked when i tried it at home. I found out the office firewall blocks actions like these.